# what is the eigenvalue and eigenvector of a matrix with the same value as diagonal but the rest of the matrix is 1

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question I'm trying to solve and have some intuition but need help with framing and formalizing it.

I have a matrix $$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
 d&  1&  1&...&1\\ 
 1&  d&  1&...   &1\\ 
 1&  1&  d& ...&1\\ 
 1&  1&  1& d&1\\ 
 1&  1&  1& ...&d
\end{pmatrix}$$

I need to show what the eigenvalue and eigenvector are.  I am being very blunt and need some more explanation on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter has answered it completely and +1 for that. Let me add some more. 
First an observation on this type of matrices: a matrix in which the sum of entries in any row is a fixed constant (in your case it is $d+n-1$) has the vector $(1,1,\ldots,1)^t$ as an eigenvector with that row sum as eigenvalue.

Now a conceptual observation: your matrix is real symmetric. So  the eigenvectors are orthogonal. So other eigenvectors are of the form $v=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ with $\sum x_i=0$. For this $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace an obvious basis is the set $e_1-e_2, e_2-e_3,\ldots, e_{n-1}-e_n$, found by Peter above. (This is also the basis for the standard representation of the symmetric group $S_n$). When we multiply $A$ by $e_i-e_{i+1}$ the resulting vetor is the subtraction of $(i+1)$th coumn from the $i$th column, and checked to be eigen vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ be the number of rows of $A$.

$d-1$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity $n-1$ because the matrix $A-(d-1)I$ contains
only 1's

The corresponding eigenvectors are $(-1,1,0,0,0,...) , (-1,0,1,0,0,...) , ... , (-1,0,...,0,1)$

$d+n-1$ is also an eigenvalue because the vector $(1,...,1)$ with $n$ 1's is an
eigenvector.

There are no more eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  \det(A -\lambda I) & = \begin{vmatrix}
 d-\lambda& 1& 1&\cdots&1\\
 1& d-\lambda& 1&\cdots &1\\
 1& 1& d-\lambda& \cdots&1\\
 \vdots& \vdots& \vdots&\ddots &\vdots\\
 1& 1& 1& \cdots&d-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}\\[1.5ex]&= \begin{vmatrix}
 d-\lambda +  n-1& d-\lambda + n-1&d-\lambda + n-1&\cdots&d-\lambda +  n-1\\
 1& d-\lambda& 1&\cdots &1\\
 1& 1& d-\lambda& \cdots &1\\
 \vdots& \vdots& \vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
 1& 1& 1&\cdots &d-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}\\[1.5ex]
&= (d-\lambda + n-1)\begin{vmatrix}
 1& 1&1&\cdots&1\\
 1& d-\lambda& 1&\cdots &1\\
 1& 1& d-\lambda& \cdots&1\\
 \vdots& \vdots& \vdots&\ddots &\vdots\\
 1& 1& 1& \cdots &d-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}\\[1.5ex]
 & = (d-\lambda + n-1)\begin{vmatrix}
 1& 1&1&\cdots&\\
 0& d-\lambda-1& 0&\cdots &0\\
 0& 0& d-\lambda-1& \cdots&0\\
 \vdots& \vdots&\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
 0& 0& 0&\cdots&d-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}\\[1.5ex]
& = (d-\lambda + n-1)(d-\lambda -1)^{n-1}
\end{align*}

Hence 1 simple eigenvalue: $ \,\lambda = d + n-1$ and one eigenvalue with multiplicity $ n-1 $:  $ \,\lambda = d -1$.

Comment: Can this be easily generalized to find the eigenvector?